# Julia: Convert numeric string to float or int

Tags: string, floating-point, type-conversion, julia

I am trying to write numeric data pulled from a database into a `Float64[]`. The original data is in `::ASCIIString` format, so trying to push it to the array gives the following error:

```
julia> push!(a, "1")
ERROR: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{Float64}, ::ASCIIString)
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Float64(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Closest candidates are:
  call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
  convert(::Type{Float64}, ::Int8)
  convert(::Type{Float64}, ::Int16)
  ...
 in push! at array.jl:432
```

Attempting to convert the data directly unsurprisingly throws the same error:

```
julia> convert(Float64, "1")
ERROR: MethodError: `convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{Float64}, ::ASCIIString)
This may have arisen from a call to the constructor Float64(...),
since type constructors fall back to convert methods.
Closest candidates are:
  call{T}(::Type{T}, ::Any)
  convert(::Type{Float64}, ::Int8)
  convert(::Type{Float64}, ::Int16)
  ...
```

Given that I know the data is numeric, is there a way I can convert it before pushing?

p.s. I am using version 0.4.0

Comment: BTW consider using `tryparse(Float64,x)` instead of `parse`. It returns a Nullable Float which is null in the case string doesn't parse well.

Comment: Good suggestion, cheers. BTW if you want to write up an answer I'll accept it, otherwise I'll just write something for the sake of completeness in day or two.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can `parse(Float64,"1")` from a string. Or in the case of a vector

```
map(x->parse(Float64,x),stringvec)
```

will parse the whole vector.

BTW consider using `tryparse(Float64,x)` instead of parse. It returns a `Nullable{Float64}` which is null in the case string doesn't parse well. For example:

```
isnull(tryparse(Float64,"33.2.1")) == true
```

And usually one would want a default value in case of a parse error:

```
strvec = ["1.2","NA","-1e3"]
map(x->(v = tryparse(Float64,x); isnull(v) ? 0.0 : get(v)),strvec)
# gives [1.2,0.0,-1000.0]
```

Comment: Commenting in 2021: what is `Nullable{T}`? It looks like it should be `Union{Nothing,T}`? And should `isnull` be `isnothing` (or `=== nothing`) now?

Answer (score 9):

Use `parse(Float64,"1")`.

See more at: [parse specification](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/numbers/#Base.parse)

Comment: In the meantime (with Julia 1.0 out), the link to use is https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/base/numbers/#Base.parse

Comment: Now its https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/numbers/#Base.parse

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers are good, however, I had expand on them:

```
#col1 = df[:,3]
col1 = ["1.2", "NA", "", Base.missing, "-1e3"]

# I do not like writing unreadable code like this:
col2 = map(x->(x=ismissing(x) ? "" : x; x=tryparse(Float64,x); isnothing(x) ? missing : x), col1)
```

returns **Array{Float64,1}** if original data was all numbers:

```
5-element Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}:
     1.2
      missing
      missing
      missing
 -1000.0
```

Alternative (explained):

```
function convert_to_float(column)
    new_column = map(x -> (
            x = ismissing(x) ? "" : x;  # no method matching tryparse(::Type{Float64}, ::Missing)
            x = tryparse(Float64, x);   # returns: Float64 or nothing
            isnothing(x) ? missing : x; # options: missing, or "", or 0.0, or nothing
            ), column)  # input 
    # returns Array{Float64,1} OR Array{Union{Missing, Float64},1}
    return new_column
end
```